# What's the purpose of ".map(|&x| x)" in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and noticed the following iterator pattern in a number of places:

```rust
let some_vector: &[& str] = &["hello", "world", "zombies", "pants"];
let result: Vec<&str> = some_vector
    .iter()
    .filter(|&x| *x == "hello")
    .map(|&x| x)
    .collect();
```

What's the purpose of that `.map(|&x| x)`? Why is it necessary? Does it create a copy?

When I remove it, I get the following compiler error:

```rust
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&&str`
    --> src/main.rs:7:6
     |
7    |     .collect();
     |      ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&&str>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<&&str>` is not implemented for `Vec<&str>`
note: required by a bound in `collect`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

So the `map` turns an iterator over references to string slices into an iterator over string slices? Removing one level of indirection? Is that right?

Comment: The `map()` moves the `x` out of the reference. In this case, moving `&&str` to `&str`, for which `.collect()` can create a Vector from. So you are right, it removes a level of indirection. Consider this rust playground for example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=291a31b8b09341f363916ab0ebca8296

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using 2021 edition, it converts from `impl Iterator< Item = &&str>` to `impl Iterator< Item = &str>`:

```
let some_vector: &[& str] = &["hello", "world", "zombies", "pants"];
let result: Vec<&str> = some_vector // &[&str]
    .iter()                         // Iter<&str>
    .filter(|&x| *x == "hello")     // Impl Iterator< Item = &&str>
    .map(|&x| x)                    // Impl Iterator< Item = &str>
    .collect();
```

And the reason it's necessary is because the `FromIterator` trait is already implemented for `&str` as it's a relatively more common use case and it's not implemented for `&&str` as the error message says:

```
the trait `FromIterator<&&str>` is not implemented for `Vec<&str>`
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @AlexW's answer, actually there is no need to write that, because there is a builtin iterator adapter that does it better (more clear, more performant): [`copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied).

```rust
let some_vector: &[&str] = &["hello", "world", "zombies", "pants"];
let result: Vec<&str> = some_vector
    .iter()
    .filter(|&x| *x == "hello")
    .copied()
    .collect();
```

There is also [`cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) which is equal to `.map(|x| x.clone())`.

Comment: Ah perfect, the documentation is really helpful here. It uses almost the same code, too! Can you explain how I can tell from the function signature of `copied()` that `&x` is turned into `x`? I don't know how to glean this information from the docs. The `map` is more explicit.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer Beside being explicitly stated on the documentation ("This is useful when you have an iterator over `&T`, but you need an iterator over `T`) and in the function name (like `Copy`), you can also see its signature requires `Self: Iterator<Item = &T>` and it returns an iterator adapter (`Copied`) that yields `T`.